# Does Apple Watch Series 4 with LTE require paid service for the fall detection call to work?

Tags: apple-watch

Does Apple Watch Series 4 with LTE require paid service for the fall detection call to work?

Will it make the call anyways? I’ve heard 911 calls don’t require paid service.

Comment: See the footnotes in the attached article. It shows that in some areas paid service is optional but that Activation is mandatory. I would establish service for at least one month if you hope for this to work. I would also test it - staying on the line saying you needed to test the function.  Be sure to pre-scchedule your test - https://www.911.gov/frequently_asked_questions.html